# Grails change locale

Tags: spring, grails

How to change `locale` in grails application and force the browser to use the same. I tried this solution.

```
def locale = new Locale("de","DE")
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale)
```

Also tried to change browser location as well nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of params.lang. I use a grails filter to set the language on every request, e.g.

```
    languageFilter(controller: '*', action: '*')
    {
        before = {          
            params.lang = "de"

            return true;
        }
    }
```